# New to sqlite and database work, how do I do this query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a project I am working on and I am wanting to create a query that involves two tables from my database as pictured below.

[image]

What I want from the query is if DMN_LIST_COLS on the DOMAIN data table equals 1 I want to retrieve all the values from DMV_VALUE_1 of the DOMAIN_VALUE data table.  What is the correct format for this query?

I know the query below is incorrect but how do I change this?

```
SELECT DMV_VALUE_1 FROM DOMAIN_VALUE WHERE DMN_LIST_COLS='1' FROM DOMAIN
```

Comment: How are the two tables related? Is `DOMAIN.DMN_LIST_COLS` = `DOMAIN_VALUE.DMV_ID` ?

Comment: DOMAIN.DMN_ID is related to DOMAIN_VALUE.DMV_ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT DOMAIN_VALUE.DMV_VALUE_1
FROM DOMAIN_VALUE INNER JOIN DOMAIN ON DOMAIN_VALUE.DMV_ID = DOMAIN.DMN_ID
WHERE DOMAIN.DMN_LIST_COLS ='1';
```

If DOMAIN.DMN_LIST_COLS contains actual numbers instead of text, you will want to remove the single quotes surrounding the 1 in the WHERE statement.